# Error on creating database in phppgadmin

Tags: database, postgresql-9.2, phppgadmin

I have PostgreSQL 9.2.0. On clicking create database it shows following error:

```
SQL error:
ERROR:  column "spclocation" does not exist
LINE 1: ...pg_catalog.pg_get_userbyid(spcowner) AS spcowner, spclocatio...
                                                         ^
In statement:

SELECT spcname, pg_catalog.pg_get_userbyid(spcowner) AS spcowner, spclocation,
       (SELECT description FROM pg_catalog.pg_shdescription pd WHERE pg_tablespace.oid=pd.objoid) AS spccomment
        FROM pg_catalog.pg_tablespace WHERE spcname NOT LIKE $$pg\_%$$ ORDER BY spcname
```

Comment: Wow, 6 months later its still not fixed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I updated to Mountain Lion on my Mac Mini Server on the evening of 12/12/2012 which runs PostgreSQL 9.2.1.  I had the same problem when I found this question.  When I did a search about this problem I found the following bug tracker on the matter.

http://sourceforge.net/tracker/?func=detail&aid=3570272&group_id=37132&atid=418980

One of the comments suggests to download the developer branch from github to get around this from https://github.com/phppgadmin/phppgadmin/zipball/master.  I did this and copied the to /Library/Server/Web/Data/Sites/Default and renamed the folder.  I modified $conf['servers'][0]['host'] to 127.0.0.1 in /conf/config.inc.php.  I think I had to copy config.inc.php-dist.  I have been successful in creating databases.  As of 12/12 they had not released a stable version for 9.2.  Hopefully they will soon.

Answer (score 13):

Quick Fix: (worked with my Version (5.0.3) / pg 9.2.3 )

1. change to `/classes/database`
2. copy `Postgres84.php` to `Postgres92.php`
3. open `Connection.php`
4. add a line  `case '9.2': return 'Postgres92'; break;` at the `// Detect version and choose appropriate database driver` switch.
5. open `Postgres.php` and copy functions `getTablespaces` + `getTablespace`
6. open `Postgres92.php` and paste the functions into the class
7. replace "`, spclocation,`" with "`, pg_tablespace_location(oid) as
   spclocation,`" in both functions.
8. in Postgres92.php change class name to Postgres92

Comment: Great solution! I applied this to cpanel in /usr/local/cpanel/base/3rdparty/phpPgAdmin/classes/database/* and it worked beautifully

Comment: Also in Postgres92.php change class name to Postgres92

Answer (score 2):

In short: table `pg_tablespace` [does not have that column in 9.2](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/static/catalog-pg-tablespace.html).

It seems that information should be obtained from other means now, as mentioned in [the mailing list](http://archives.postgresql.org/pgsql-bugs/2012-06/msg00201.php).

Also notice how in the [official phpPgAdmin page](http://phppgadmin.sourceforge.net/doku.php), the latest PostgreSQL supported version is 9.0.

Answer (score 1):

And for 'Quick Fix', add one more step after (2):

Change the class name in Postgres92.php from Postgres84 to Postgres92.